# How to create github.io pages for a course using rmarkdown::render_site()

Tags: github, r-markdown, knitr, github-pages

I'm confused about the organization of files for a course built
using `rmarkdown::render_site()` and to be deployed on github
as `my_name.github.io/course_name`

- Github pages creates the web pages from the `docs/` directory, whereas
  `render_site` places them in a `_site` directory.  Will it work if
  I just use:

  output_dir = docs

in my `_site.yml` file?  Or is there a different way to do this?

My local project directory looks like this.

```
+-- about.Rmd
+-- examples
+-- exercises
+-- fig
+-- footer.html
+-- images
+-- index.Rmd
+-- lectures
|   +-- lecture1.pdf
|   +-- lecture1.pptx
|   +-- lecture1.Rmd
|   +-- lecture2.pdf
|   +-- lecture2.pptx
|   +-- lecture3.pdf
|   \-- lecture3.pptx
++-- R
+-- resources.Rmd
+-- styles.css
+-- _site
+-- _site.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I didn't realized it was as easy as just using

```
output_dir = docs
```